# Alert successful google extension installation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i have a webpage with a link to a google chrome extension. After if it installed, I want an alert indicating it has been installed. i have tried to put this script on the page and it doesn't work.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
var first_run = true;
if (!localStorage['ran_before']) {
  first_run = false;
  localStorage['ran_before'] = '1';
}

if (ran_before) alert('i have been installed!');

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slim this down quite a bit and make it a lot easier to read.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (localStorage.getItem('installed') !== 'true') {
  localStorage.setItem('installed', 'true');
  alert('i have been installed!')
}
</script>
```